# How to use tf.transformPose of tf mpdule?

Tags: ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS melodic of Ubuntu 18.04.

I recently heard that `tf` module has the special class function which transforms a specific pose into the pose of another specific frame.

I tried calling `tf.TransformerROS.transformPose`, but I've just gotten only this error:

```
"/sensor_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist
```

.
Of course, I double-checked that `/sensor_frame` was practically running.
(I tried

> $ rosrun tf tf_echo

and also checked it on `rviz` tool.)

Below is my code,

```
import rospy
import tf
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped


def talker():
  pub = rospy.Publisher('/that', PoseStamped, queue_size = 10)
  rate = rospy.Rate(10)

   # goaler = tf.TransformerROS()
   goaler = tf.TransformListener()

   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      goal = PoseStamped()
      goal.pose.position.x = 5.0
      goal.pose.position.y = 5.0

      # ret = goaler.transformPose("lidar_sensor_link", goal)
      ret = goaler.transformPose("/sonar2_link", goal)

      pub.publish(ret)
      rate.sleep()



 if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('pracd')

    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

(Just so you know, I referred to [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html))

I'm not familiar with `tf`, so I 'm suffered from fixing..

What should I do to coordinate transformation works?

Thanks inadvance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349435/how-to-use-tf.transformpose-of-tf-mpdule?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To start off with you should use tf2 not tf. tf has been deprecated for several years now and tf2 has a superset of it's functionality. https://wiki.ros.org/tf2

And to understand how it works there are tutorials: https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials

It looks like you're using the API correctly but you likely need to make sure that the rest of your system is setup correctly to support the coordinate frames that you intend to query.

For completeness there are [tf tutorials as well](https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials). But if you're just getting started you should really move forward.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1